# Como eu desabilito a selecao de texto no clique do botao direito?

Tags: javascript, osx

Eu não quero desabilitar a seleção de texto, nem quero desabilitar o clique do botão direito. Eu quero APENAS desabilitar a seleção de texto COM o clique do botão direito do mouse (mas o menu ainda deve aparecer ao clicar com o botão direito e, selecionar texto via clicar duas vezes ou clicar + arrastar também dever continuar funcionando)

Comment: Nao sei como funciona no Windows, mas no Mac, se voce clicar com o botao direito do mouse em qualquer palavra (mesmo que esta esteja dentro de outro elemento, como um botao), alem de abir o menu, a palavra fica selecionada.

Comment: @user23536 entendi, infelizmente não tenho um MAC para testar a situação, mas talvez eu poste um exemplo, a situação é só no Mac mesmo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Dei uma pesquisada no Google e me parece que e so no MAC mesmo.

Comment: Acredito que os eventos de mouse sejam compativeis e podemos bloquear pelo próprio evento `contextmenu`, usando `textrange` ou algo assim, a noite eu tento adicionar uma resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ok, obrigado pela atencao. :)

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa resposta:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326004/prevent-selection-in-html

Answer (score 3):

Existem duas formas usando CSS (que eu saiba):

- [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events): faz com que a interação do ponteiro do mouse com o elemento seja passado para o elemento de trás. Isso impossibilita clicar no elemento em si, e no caso de um botão... vai torná-lo inútil. Além disso, se começar a seleção a partir do elemento anterior, ai vai ser possível selecionar o texto.

  Para funcionar, você poderia fazer o elemento que contém texto ter `pointer-events: none`, sendo que o elemento por baixo dele é que abre de fato o menu.
- [`user-select: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select): impede que o texto do elemento seja selecionado. Cada browser trata isso de uma forma diferente, pois não é padronizado pela W3C. Por isso é necessário usar prefixos de fabricante: `-moz`, `-webkit` e `-ms`. [Já se tentou padronizar isso](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select), mas [não faz mais parte do CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/).

  Nota da MDN:

  > Note: user-select is not currently part of any W3C CSS specification.
  >   As such, there are minor differences between the browser
  >   implementations. Be sure to test your application across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode aproveitar o evento que abre o menu de contexto, e limpar qualquer seleção a partir dali:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});
```

Recomendo testar isso em vários browsers, pois a API de seleções ainda não está estável. Veja também a [documentação do método `removeAllRanges`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/removeAllRanges), bem como o material disponível para `Selection` e `Range`, disponível a partir do link do método.